# library variable in jenkins shared library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-shared-libraries

I have a Jenkins shared lib in a repo, usual folder structure:

```
vars
  utils.groovy
```

In utils.groovy I have some functions:

```
void funcA() {}
void funcB() {}
```

Now I want to define a constant that all functions in that module can use, but when I try this:

```
String common='hi'
void funcA() {println "A ${common}"}
void funcB() {println "B ${common}"}
```

I get an exception that common is not a symbol that exists:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: common for class: utils
```

For now I'm getting around the issue by doing this hack:

```
String _getCommon() {
    return 'hi'
}
void funcA() {String common=_getCommon(); println "A ${common}"}
void funcB() {String common=_getCommon(); println "B ${common}"}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Module level variables can be defined via the @Field:

```
import groovy.transform.Field
@Field var =...
void func() {println var}
```

Other modules in the same library can reference it too, the usual way. Ex assuming the above was defined in utils.groovy the other.groovy could have:

```
void func() {println utils.var}
```

See http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html.

Comment: Nice. Access even works from within the Jenkinsfile itself (using `utils.var`).

Comment: Actually with this solution you can't override `utils.var` from within your pipeline. If you want to do that (e.g. for configuration) the solution from Joerg S works

Comment: @MarcusHeld just define a setter function in the lib. With my solution, you don't need that innerclass that Joerg defines, and the code is a lot simpler.

Comment: I gave it a try but setting the variable from another script didn't work. It ended up to be null, for some reason.

Comment: OK I'll have another at my code, I'm pretty sure I've done that but maybe not.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the CPS class loader does not support simple properties.
However turns out that you can use something like:

```
class InnerClass {
    static String myProperty = 'Hi'
}

String setCommon(String value) {
    InnerClass.myProperty = value
}

String getCommon() {
    return InnerClass.myProperty
}

void funcA() {println "A ${common}"}
void funcB() {println "B ${common}"}
```

Having this you may also access the property from within your Jenkinsfile like:

```
@Library('cpsLibFoo') _

utils.funcA()
utils.common = 'baz'
utils.funcB()
```

Output will be:

```
[Pipeline] echo
A Hi
[Pipeline] echo
B baz
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, I would not have thought of that. But I found a much simpler approach, I have posted.

Comment: CPS doesn't seem to serialize static fields. That means after Jenkins restart if there was any state saved in to that variable - that state will be lost.